# Set up NSBlock operation that waits for async calls from other block operations to complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

I may be asking the impossible here, but how can I use NSOperationQueues to dispatch a number of asynchronous calls to HealthKit and only run a final operation when all those async calls have completed?

Here's how I make an array of block operations, each of which has an asynchronous call to HealthKit:

```
   for( NSString *hkType in typesToRetrieve){
        NSBlockOperation *newOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
                [self getAllStoredDataForHKQuantityIdentifier: hkType withCompletion:^(NSArray *results) {
                    [self processActivityResultsArray:results];
                }];
            }
        }];
        [loadingOperations addObject:newOp];
    }
```

And here's how I add these operations:

```
for ( NSBlockOperation* blockOp in loadingOperations){
    [endOperation addDependency:blockOp];
    [retrievalOperationQueue addOperation:blockOp];
}
```

The problem is that `endOperation` is firing when the blocks have returned but not when their asycn calls have returned. Is there a clever way to keep things modular, as they are now, but wait for the async calls to return from the HealthKit queries?

Comment: Since the health kit method is already asynchronous the block operations probably aren't helping you.  Have a look at GCD `dispatch_group`.  You can create a group, have each iteration of your loop enter the group with `dispatch_group_enter`, leave the group in the completion handler (`dispatch_group_leave`) and use a `dispatch_group_notify` to execute a block when everything is done.